# Скрипт на роутере

Tags: python-3.x, linux

у меня есть роутер у которого флеш память 10МБ, вся память разделена на tmpfs и ubifs
есть microusb но, не получилось монтировать присоединив флешку.
Мне требуется закинуть туда скрипт который будет устанавливать сокет с конкретным адресом подсети роутера по lan и перенаправлять все сообщения от сокет клиента дальше на какой-то внешний адрес, беда в том что на python3.10 на котором я написал я не смог его там разместить, как и после конвертации в С он весит слишком много, подскажите, пожалуйста, куда можно копнуть, perl тоже пробовал но память не хватило, при всем при этом там довольно не много по коду выходит в скрипте(поднять 1 сокет, отослать 2 сообщения клиенту и все остальные сообщения от клиента отсылать дальше не закрывая сокет), Я не смог найти других роутеров которые бы соответствовали, и по размеру и по техническим особенностям

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Compilers/comments/119zcvq/how_big_is_your_interpreter/

Answer (score 1):

socat поставь. Эта программа может соединить что угодно с чем угодно.